# dotnetacademy Exercise 7.1 - Inheritence and Abstract Classes with Override?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

I am working my way through the C# tutorials on this site, and I am getting stuck on this exercise.  I got stuck on 5.1 and a C# programmer I work with discovered that the issue was a freaking space. It's making it hard to see if I am getting the concepts right or not.  He said the space issue would never cause an issue compiling in reality, so it may be a bug in the validator on the site.

Anyway, I am on exercise 7.1 here: [dotnetacademy exercise 7.1](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2045/Pages/15) and I can't seem to get code to validate properly.  the steps are as follows:

1. Create an abstract class named Astrodroid that provides a virtual
   method called GetSound which returns a string. The default sound
   should be the words "Beep beep".
2. Implement a method called 'MakeSound' which writes the result of   the GetSound method to the Console followed by a new line.
3. Create a derived class named R2 that inherits from Astrodroid.
4. Override the GetSound method on the R2 class so that it returns "Beep bop".

This is the code I wrote up:

```
using System;

// Implement your classes here.
public abstract class Astrodroid
{
    public virtual string GetSound { get { return "Beep beep"; } }
    
    public void MakeSound() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(GetSound); 
    }
    
}

public class R2 : Astrodroid
{
    public override string GetSound { get { return "Beep bob"; } }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        //var MakeSound = new R2();
        //Console.WriteLine(MakeSound.GetSound);
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

> Not all requirements have been met.
>
> You must define a method named GetSound that returns a string.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `GetSound` as a property, not a method.

`public override string GetSound() { return "Beep bob"; }` is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, much! That really helps me not just get the solution, but understand the objects, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to make your tests work:

```
var MakeSound = new R2();
Console.WriteLine(MakeSound.GetSound());
```